# Join on field with multiple values

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, spatial-join, array

I have a field *"istat"* that contains multiple values ​​of the istat code (municipal code):

[image]

and a table containing the centroids of the municipalities

[image]

I am looking for a way to join the *"istat"*-fields of the two tables in order to create a table with multipoint geometry with the centroids of the common.

I thought of creating as many *"istat"* columns as the maximum number of *"istat"*-codes present in a cell, doing a multiple join.

Finally combine all the `geom` fields creating a multipoint field (if it is possible to do such a thing).

Comment: Thank you @BERA, it works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can directly `JOIN` on the array members:

```
SELECT a.<id>,
       ST_Collect(b.centroid) AS geom
FROM   <base_table> AS a
JOIN   <centroid_table> AS b
  ON   b.istat = ANY(a.istat)
GROUP BY
       a.<id>
;
```

This may profit from a `GIN` index on `a.istat`.

---

In case you are having a `TEXT` column rather than an `ARRAY`, you can pre-serialize your string into an array:

```
SELECT a.<id>,
       ST_Collect(b.centroid) AS geom
FROM   <base_table> AS a
JOIN   <centroid_table> AS b
  ON   b.istat = ANY(STRING_TO_ARRAY(a.istat, ', ')::<TYPE>[])
GROUP BY
       a.<id>
;
```

where you need to replace `<TYPE>` with the actual data type you are working with in both tables, if different than `TEXT`

Comment: Wonderful! 
Until now I had never used the array function. Very interesting. Thank you very much

Comment: @DanielePiccolo make sure you are using the `<base_table>.<id>` to `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Sorry @geozelot.. just missing a space next to, to define the array. 
I had already deleted my comment